H-bridge transistors are too hot
I have built the following H bridge for driving my 48V 500W spindle for my DIY CNC Mill. The optocoupler part works well and I started to test the H bridge, however the transistors are heating up like crazy even without load on the motor.
It feels like 70-80°C after a few seconds of starting the motor. It was only tested with 20V and maximum 0,5A.
What could be the problem and how could I solve this? Do heatsink's count this much? The transistors are: https://www.hestore.hu/prod_getfile.php?id=9060


Welcome! Switching or static forward/reverse operation?

@winny Switching operation

@greybeard  °C (corrected it), doing this as a part of my thesis and my teacher was more confident in transistors instead of MOSFETs..., anyway this is all assembled and we are testing it now

(1N5404G seems to be somewhat slow - what's the intended PWM pulse width/frequency?)

Here is the exact BOM: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KvOBUdNW0pEOhdf-Bm1-WI6yH5ELidsqCt85Wvawq6g/edit?usp=sharing
What tests sould I do with oscilloscope and function generator?

You didn’t specify frequency, but apart from the Darlington+emitter follower issues already mentioned, your drive strength is low, which will mean switching losses too.

I ran a quick simulation...

X1 is a Darlington transistor used as follower, so its Vce will be 2*Vbe plus voltage drop in R1, so about 1.5V. With 400mA through the load it dissipates 0.6W. With the intended current (say 10A) through the load, voltage drop in R1 increases due to extra base current, so it will dissipate about 40W.
X6 is also a Darlington used as follower, its Vce will be 2 Vbe plus Vcesat of X6 so about 2-2.3V. Thus it dissipates 0.9W with the test current of 400mA, and would also burn 40W at 10A current.
TO220 without heat sink has a thermal resistance of about 70 °C/W so it would be expected to have a temperature rise of 70°C/W x 0.9W = 56°C above ambient for X5, so your fingers seem to be well calibrated...
Basically if you use Darlington BJTs, you will get quite a large voltage drop, it's inevitable. With 40W per transistor you will need a large heat sink and most likely a fan. Or you could use 10 mOhm MOSFETs which will dissipate 1W at 10A and work fine without heat sink.
One solution would be to use a readymade motor controller or build one with MOSFETs and a full bridge driver.

Where do you see the 70*C/W spec? The BDW94FC has 1.56 listed and the BDW47G has 1.47 listed.

1.47 is from junction to case (metal tab). It's a relevant spec if you mount it on a heat sink. So if you add thermal pad (say 1¨C/W) and a heat sink/fan (1°C/W) you get about 3.5°C/W total. It will still fry at 40W, that's too much for TO220. But if there's no heat sink, then you have to add the thermal resistance from package to air, which is about 70°C/W for TO220.

Wow thank you for the thoughtful comment!

You're welcome ;) Now you get the tough job of explaining to the professor that his idea of using 1980's tech was perhaps not optimal for the current year lol

I was designing with MOSFET-s first before I asked him to look at it

Damn what a waste of your time

Would replacing the power transistors with MOSFETS be somewhat of a solution?

Yes, but not in this circuit. You need a real bridge driver. If the subject of your work is designing a bridge, then you can ask a question about that and you'll get help. If you need a bridge right now, then the best solution is to buy one from an outlet like robotshop, it will save a lot of time and money.

If 40W is soo much how can the datasheet write, that P_tot (Total Dissipation at Tc ≤25C) = 80W?

That's at Tc<25°C. Every transistor datasheet specs this at 25°C, the point of this spec is to compare transistors in a hypothetical situation. If you actually want to keep the back of the transistor at 25°C while dissipating 80W, you'd need to solder it on a copper cpu waterblock held around 0°C with a compressor chiller...

For fixing ideas, I also made a simulation with a 5 Ohm load.
I had to change some resistors values.



So the main problem is the 40W on the transistors and the spikes

Yes, the main problem is the power on the transistors (~ 30 W for ~ 350 W output)
